# Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, realm

I am downloading JSON data from a url and since i plan it to use across many activities, i am storing it offline using Realm, now when i try to access the stored data from mainactivity, it is working fine, but the data is such that, it is a arraylist consisting of two more arraylists (nested arraylists).
So whenever i want to access one of the arraylists of the main object in the second screen, i am sending the position of the object from main to second. and am trying to get the data from there. but it is showing that error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Stack Trace

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.vamshi.baking, PID: 2643
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vamshi.baking/com.example.vamshi.baking.UI.SecondScreenDetails}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
                                                                             at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:385)
                                                                             at io.realm.IngredientsRealmProxy.realmGet$quantity(IngredientsRealmProxy.java:98)
                                                                             at com.example.vamshi.baking.Data.Ingredients.getQuantity(Ingredients.java:28)
                                                                             at com.example.vamshi.baking.UI.SecondScreenDetails.setDisplay(SecondScreenDetails.java:63)
                                                                             at com.example.vamshi.baking.UI.SecondScreenDetails.onCreate(SecondScreenDetails.java:42)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
07-04 17:42:44.452 2643-2643/com.example.vamshi.baking E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static ListView myList;
    public static ListAdapter myAdapter;
    public static Realm realm;


    @Override
    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        DownloadTask newTask = new DownloadTask();
        newTask.execute("hi");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Recipe_list);

       // getData();

        setDisplay();

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String p = String.valueOf(position);
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreenDetails.class);
                in.putExtra("Position", p);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

    }

    public void setDisplay(){

        ArrayList<Recipe> finalRecipies = new ArrayList<>();
        RealmResults<Recipe> rrRecipies = realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll();

        for(Recipe r: rrRecipies){
            finalRecipies.add(r);
//            Toast.makeText(this, r.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        myAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, finalRecipies);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        realm.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

SecondScreenActivity (Problem Activity)

```
    public class SecondScreenDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Realm realm;
    @BindView(R.id.ingredients_list)RecyclerView ingre_list;
    @BindView(R.id.steps_button)Button next_button;
    public int position;
    public static SecondScreenRecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen_details);
        Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setDisplay();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setDisplay() {
        ArrayList<Recipe> finalRecipies = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Ingredients> finalIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
        RealmResults<Recipe> rrRecipies = realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll();
        Intent in = getIntent();
        position = Integer.parseInt(in.getStringExtra("Position"));
        for(Recipe r: rrRecipies){
            finalRecipies.add(r);
        }
        int i = finalRecipies.get(position).getIngredients().size();
        for( int j = 0 ; j<i ; j++){
            Ingredients n = new Ingredients(finalRecipies.get(position).getIngredients().get(j).getQuantity(),
                    finalRecipies.get(position).getIngredients().get(j).getMeasure(),
                    finalRecipies.get(position).getIngredients().get(j).getIngredient());
            finalIngredients.add(n);
        }
        myAdapter = new SecondScreenRecyclerViewAdapter(finalIngredients);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        ingre_list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        ingre_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        ingre_list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

DownloadingData Class

```
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    private RealmList<Recipe> realmRecipe = new RealmList<>();
    String result;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        result = "";
        Realm realm = null;
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json").build();
                    try {
                        result = client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
                        Log.i("RESULT", result);
                        JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject tempObject = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jIngredients = tempObject.getJSONArray("ingredients");
                            JSONArray jSteps = tempObject.getJSONArray("steps");

                            // Get the ingredients
                            List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jIngredients.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject tempIngredient = jIngredients.getJSONObject(j);
                                Ingredients nIngredient = realm.createObject(Ingredients.class);
                                nIngredient.setIngredient(tempIngredient.getString("ingredient"));
                                nIngredient.setMeasure(tempIngredient.getString("measure"));
                                nIngredient.setQuantity(tempIngredient.getString("quantity"));
//                                Ingredients newIngredient = new Ingredients(tempIngredient.getString("quantity"),
//                                        tempIngredient.getString("measure"),
//                                        tempIngredient.getString("ingredient"));
//                                ingredients.add(newIngredient);
                                ingredients.add(nIngredient);
                            }

                            // Get the steps
                            List<Steps> steps = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jSteps.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject tempStep = jSteps.getJSONObject(j);
                                Steps nStep = realm.createObject(Steps.class);
                                nStep.setDescription(tempStep.getString("description"));
                                nStep.setId(tempStep.getString("id"));
                                nStep.setShortDescription(tempStep.getString("shortDescription"));
                                nStep.setVideoURL(tempStep.getString("videoURL"));
                                steps.add(nStep);
//                                Steps newStep = new Steps(tempStep.getString("id"), tempStep.getString("shortDescription"),
//                                        tempStep.getString("description"), tempStep.getString("videoURL"));
//                                steps.add(newStep);
                            }

                            // Create the recipe

                            Recipe nRecipe = realm.createObject(Recipe.class);
                            nRecipe.setId(tempObject.getString("id"));
                            nRecipe.setName(tempObject.getString("name"));
                            nRecipe.setServings(tempObject.getString("servings"));
                            nRecipe.setIngredients(ingredients);
                            nRecipe.setSteps(steps);
                            realmRecipe.add(nRecipe);
//                            Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe(tempObject.getString("id"), tempObject.getString("name"), tempObject.getString("servings"), ingredients, steps);
//                            MainActivity.mRecipies.add(newRecipe);

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.i("Error Message", e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of Realm is this?

Comment: its the latest one ( 3.4.0 )

Comment: Having `private RealmList<Recipe> realmRecipe = new RealmList<>();` as a field in you AsyncTask, looks like an easy way to accidentally access data from the wrong thread. I would start by removing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract all the logic of the data request within the AsyncTask, and within decide whether to return realm data or service data.

Comment: im sorry, i dint get you